# Selecting specific range pixel values using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, masking, normalized-difference-water-index, operator

I have calculated NDWI on my study area. After this, I want to select a specific range of values that I will use to make a mask. My specific values range  is between 0.2 and -0.1.

This is my code:

```
var sentinel = collezione.filterBounds(area)
                         .filterDate('2020-10-10','2020-10-28')
                         .select('B4','B3','B2','B8','TCI_B','TCI_R','TCI_G')
                         .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')
                         .first()
                         .clip(area);

var ndwi = sentinel.normalizedDifference(['B3','B8']);
var palette_NDWI = ['de0000','ff4000','ff7a20','ffc522','fffd30'];
var maschera = ndwi.lt(0.2).and(ndwi.gt(-0.1))
var filtro = sentinel.updateMask(maschera2)

Map.addLayer(filtro)
```

I don't have my expected mask. What should I do? Is there some operator that can extract my range?

Answer (score 1):

As you don't provide your study area, I arbitrarily assign one in my script. My Image Collection was 'COPERNICUS/S2_SR' (you don't provide one specific product; only the key word **sentinel**). So, my complete [script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/ffe6c1da741f37e87e82da61df5d4081) looks as follows:

```
var area = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[-108.647265625, 39.574670896812535],
          [-104.16484375, 41.247551055345276],
          [-104.340625, 43.58306796571101],
          [-107.32890625, 44.27931722642314],
          [-110.3171875, 42.36127474502225]]]);

var pt = ee.Geometry.Point ([-105.051019, 40.581871]);

var collezione = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filterBounds(pt) //it can also be used area instead
  .filterDate('2020-10-10','2020-10-28')
  .select('B4','B3','B2','B8','TCI_B','TCI_R','TCI_G')
  .filterMetadata('MGRS_TILE', 'equals', '13TDF')
  .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')
  .first();

var sentinel = collezione;

Map.centerObject(pt, 18);

print(sentinel);

var ndwi = sentinel.normalizedDifference(['B3','B8']);

print(ndwi);

//var palette_NDWI = ['de0000','ff4000','ff7a20','ffc522','fffd30'];

var palette_NDWI = {"opacity":1,
                   "bands":["nd"],
                   "palette":['de0000','ff4000','ff7a20','ffc522','fffd30']};

var maschera = ndwi.lt(0.2).and(ndwi.gt(-0.1));
var filtro = maschera.updateMask(maschera).multiply(ndwi);

print(filtro);

Map.addLayer(filtro, palette_NDWI);
```

By using your visualization palette, after running above script in GEE code editor, I got result of following image.

[image]

It looks as you are searching for a procedure for segregating some kind of buildings. I used **Inspector Tab** for getting some unmasked values and they are as expected.

Comment: sorry for my explanation but this is my first post on this platform;

thanks for your support but on my layer i  want to show all pixels EXCEPT pixels with values comprise between 0.2 and -0.1;

so i want to do exactly the opposite of what is shown on your code;

is it possible?